# MySQL or PHP Transform rows to columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have this kind of table:

[image]

the month are dynamically generated based on user input. The month can also be repeated. However, I want to transpose the month values to columns with a value of the amount but when trying it dynamically in mysql, it does not permit me because it can only return distinct values.

I also tried removing distinct from my code below but it is not working. Any thoughts?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
SET group_concat_max_len=2048;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(month = ''',
      month,
      ''', amount, NULL)) AS ',
      month
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tmp_results;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT r.account, 
                           r.region, ', 
                           @sql, '
                   FROM tmp_results r
                   LEFT JOIN accounts AS a
                   on r.account_id = a.id
                   GROUP BY r.account');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Tried to use the collection in laravel 5 and still does nothing, If you have answer for php, I welcome it also. I'm banging my head for days to solve this.

Comment: "Does not work" is not very specific: What does not work or what error do you get? Depending on your server configuration (e.g. a 5.7 default configuration), you might have to change `r.region` to `max(r.region) as region` in your `select` or use `GROUP BY r.account, r.region`, but otherwise, on first sight, the code looks correct (apart from not checking if `tmp_results` or rather `@sql` is empty, it would result in an error in that case, but that doesn't seem to be the problem here; and it will not work if you have invalid values for `month`, e.g. `''`, or containing spaces, `-`,...).

Comment: does not work means, it did not return the result i wanted. It omitted the other months that I needed to display.

Comment: it is working, just did not return the result I expected

Comment: Could you add the result you get by that (and what you want to get)? Or explain what you mean by "omitted the other months"? With that query and your data, you should get all 12 months as columns (probably in random order, but all should be there, as long as they exist in the base table).

Comment: yes, 12 months all but If a user select 3 years, it should return 36 months but not, that's my problem

Comment: Ah ok, that was the missing piece of information. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have seperate columns for your years too, you have to add the year (calculated from your column `date`) to your dynamic sql code:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
  SET group_concat_max_len=2048;
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(month = ''',
      month,
      ''' and year(date) = ',
      year(date),
      ', amount, NULL)) AS `',
      month,
      '_',
      year(date),
      '`'
    )
    order by date
  ) INTO @sql
  FROM tmp_results;

  if coalesce(@sql,'') != '' then
    set @sql = concat(', ', @sql);
  end if; 

  SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT r.account, 
     r.region ',  
     coalesce(@sql,''),
    ' FROM tmp_results r
     LEFT JOIN accounts AS a
     on r.account_id = a.id
     GROUP BY r.account, r.region');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

The columns will be named like `January_2017`, and I added an `order by date`, otherwise they would usually be unordered.

I added a `group by r.region`, otherwise it will not work if `only_full_group_by` is enabled on your server (which is the default value starting with MySQL 5.7).

And I added a test for empty tables (which would otherwise result in an error). If you don't need it and copy only parts of my code into yours, be aware of the missing comma after `r.region` in  `SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT r.account, r.region '` compared to your code, you might have to add it again.

Since the code for each month has a length of about 80, you might have to increase `group_concat_max_len` to fit your largest possible query.

Comment: Wow you're so great! Thank you, you solved my problem. I got the idea now. First you make year and month in one string so it will not be consider as duplicate values.

Comment: Hi, I'm having problems putting a where statement and my parameter should be string, this part:

Comment: SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT r.account as Account, 
     r.region as Region,SUM(r.amount) as Total ',   
     coalesce(@sql,''),
    'FROM tmp_results r
     LEFT JOIN accounts AS a
     on r.account_id = a.id
     where a.ABE =' ,person,
     ' GROUP BY r.account, r.region
     ORDER By r.account_id');

Comment: @Dhenn Is your "person" a variable? Then you have to surround it with `'` similar to your `month`-varaible before (there it was a column, but it works the same way). So try  `... where a.ABE = ''' ,person, ''' GROUP BY...` (three single `'`)

Comment: Helo again, i have a new column and these are amounts as well but different label. How can i achieve it with the answer you provided?

Comment: Hey Solarflare, maybe you can help with this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524707/mysql-mysql-or-php-transform-rows-to-two-columns-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment68327446_40524707