# Mysql MySQL or PHP Transform rows to two columns dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have the same scenario as I have in [MySQL or PHP Transform rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829255/mysql-or-php-transform-rows-to-columns/39832881#)

But I have to restructure my table now and this is the output

[image]

It's pretty much the same with the link above but I to include the AS_amount.anyone can help me?

I want the result below but with AS_month_2016...etc in the right side of each FA_mont2016

[image]

This is my code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `display_annualize_table`()
BEGIN
SET group_concat_max_len=10028;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(month = ''',
      month,
      ''' and year(date) = ',
      year(date),

      ', FS_amount, NULL)) AS `',
      CONCAT('FA_',month),
      '_',
      year(date),

      '`')
    order by date
  ) INTO @sql
  FROM tmp_results;

  if coalesce(@sql,'') != '' then
    set @sql = concat(', ', @sql);
  end if; 

  SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT r.account as Account, 
     r.region as Region ',  
     coalesce(@sql,''),
    'FROM tmp_results r
     LEFT JOIN accounts AS a
     on r.account_id = a.id
     GROUP BY r.account, r.region
     ORDER By r.account_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Need your help please. Thank you in advance!

Comment: they have the same code as I have.

Comment: I upvoted your question, thanks for showing the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's works the same way as `FS_amount`, just add the new columns to your code that generates the dynamic columns:

```
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(month = ''',
      month,
      ''' and year(date) = ',
      year(date),
      ', FS_amount, NULL)) AS `',
      CONCAT('FA_',month),
      '_',
      year(date),
      '`, ', 
      'MAX(IF(month = ''',
      month,
      ''' and year(date) = ',
      year(date),
      ', AS_amount, NULL)) AS `',
      CONCAT('AS_',month),
      '_',
      year(date),
      '`'      
      )
    order by date
  ) INTO @sql
  FROM tmp_results;
```

You should have a look at the code the statements create (e.g. by temporary adding a `select @sql;`), although it should be pretty straight forward to add even more columns in case you'll need them.

Comment: Hi Solarflare, unfortunately I encountered an error when running this: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`FA_November_202FROM tmp_results r      LEFT JOIN accounts AS a      on r.accoun' at line 2

Comment: Oh,, I figured it out. I have to increase may max_concat_len. Thanks buddy! :)