# How to show dynamic data row to data column in mysql or within php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the same problem with (MySQL or PHP Transform rows to columns)[[Mysql MySQL or PHP Transform rows to two columns dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524707/mysql-mysql-or-php-transform-rows-to-two-columns-dynamically]). But with different header column format.

My database table

[image]

i have done with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524707/mysql-mysql-or-php-transform-rows-to-two-columns-dynamically) question, below is my query version:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(day(tanggal) = ',
      day(tanggal),
      ', presensi, NULL)) AS `',
      tanggal,
      '`, '
    order by tanggal
  ) INTO @sql
  FROM tableName;
```

when running a query it show notification "***Query executed OK, 1 row affected.***", but result is empty, this is The table expected what looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your static query:

```
select id_pegawai, 
max(if(tanggal="2019-06-13", presensi, null)) as "2019-06-13",
max(if(tanggal="2019-06-14", presensi, null)) as "2019-06-14"
from yourtable
group by id_pegawai;
```

create a dinamic query:

```
  SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
     GROUP_CONCAT(
      DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'max(if(tanggal="', 
            tanggal, 
            '", presensi, null)) as "',
            tanggal,
            '"'
        )
     ) into @sql
    FROM yourtable;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id_pegawai, ',
                        @sql, ' FROM yourtable GROUP BY id_pegawai');
```

Execute your dinamic query:

```
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

inspired from this post: http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html